# How do I build a string of variable names?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I'm trying to build a string that contains all attributes of a class-object. The object name is `jsonData` and it has a few attributes, some of them being

```
jsonData.Serial,
jsonData.InstrumentSerial,
jsonData.Country
```

I'd like to build a string that has those attribute names in the format of this:

`'Serial InstrumentSerial Country'`

End goal is to define a schema for a Spark dataframe.

I'm open to alternatives, as long as I know order of the string/object because I need to map the schema to appropriate values.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to be careful about filtering out unwanted attributes, but try this:

```
' '.join([x for x in dir(jsonData) if '__' not in x])
```

That filters out all the "magic methods" like `__init__` or `__new__`.

To include those, do

```
' '.join(dir(jsonData))
```

These take advantage of Python's `dir` method, which returns a list of all attributes of an object.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand why you want to group the attribute names in a single string.
You could simply have a list of attribute names as the order of a python list is persist.

```
attribute_names = [x for x in dir(jsonData) if '__' not in x]
```

From there you can create your dataframe. If you don't need to specify the SparkTypes,  you can just to:

```
df = SparkContext.createDataFrame(data, schema = attribute_names)
```

You could also create a `StructType` and specify the types in your schema.

I guess that you are going to have a list of `jsonData` records that you want to consider as Rows. 
Let's considered it as a list of objects, but the logic would still be the same.
You can do that as followed:

```
my_object_list = [
    jsonDataClass(Serial = 1, InstrumentSerial = 'TDD', Country = 'France'),
    jsonDataClass(Serial = 2, InstrumentSerial = 'TDI', Country = 'Suisse'),
    jsonDataClass(Serial = 3, InstrumentSerial = 'TDD', Country = 'Grece')]

def build_record(obj, attr_names):
   from operator import attrgetter
   return attrgetter(*attr_names)(obj)
```

So the data attribute referred previously would be constructed as:

```
data = [build_record(x, attribute_names) for x in my_object_list]
```